"Hot Reload" feature seems sluggish and or buggy
What I'm Building
I am building a Blazor (Interactive Server) web application using .NET 8.0
Machine & Software
I am using a Mac Pro (Intel 2019) with macOS Sonoma and Rider 2024.2. All software is up to date.
Run Configurations

.NET Launch Settings Profile (HTTP & HTTPS, Run & Debug)
.NET Watch Run

Problem
The problem I have is with the "Hot Reload" feature, which seems sluggish, and or buggy. When using the .NET launch settings profiles, and then edit something in the application, I have to manually "apply changes" to see the effects. In contrast, .NET Watch Run seems to perform most of the changes automatically, which is what I would expected from a "Hot Reload" feature.
In either case, the first few edits/updates (maybe 5 at most) appear in the browser immediately. Then they slow down and it takes a few seconds for the edits/updates to appear (maybe 3 at most). After that, any edits/updates stop altogether, and I have to restart the application.
Edit, Edit, Edit, Edit, Restart, Edit, Edit, Edit, Edit, Restart, etc.
As I'm sure you can imagine, this is rather frustrating. Has anyone else experienced the same problem, or found out how to fix it?

I have the same issues, most of the time it's not working properly. I've found out that it's working he best with .net watch or with IIS Express as hosts. There are numerous topics on this and it seems that Jetbrains still has no reliable solution to this (see docs).
Sadly Hot Reload currently works best with Visual Studio which offers the most features related to this.

Thank you for your feedback.
Need to press Apply changes every time
At the moment, the designed approach is to press "Apply Changes" manually. We are aware of the inconvenience of the current solution and are working on the improvements.
Feel free to upvote this feature request to demonstrate your interest: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-115250
Hot Reload starts working slower with time. Then stops working at all
That sounds weird. Should you wish to assist us in troubleshooting this issue, we would appreciate it if you could submit an issue to our tracker. You can use this link to open the form: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RIDER
Please, describe the same issue there and attach additional information as described below:

Enable Roslyn trace scenario via Help | Diagnostic Tools | Choose Trace Scenario;
Reproduce the issue. That would be great if you could make a recording that demonstrates the issue;
Collect logs via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data;

Attach the collected files to the issue or upload it to JetBrains Upload Service and mention upload ID in the issue.
Have a nice day!
